# Openlayers some part of drawing is invisible

Tags: javascript, drawing, openlayers

Can anyone please explain the reason why am I getting such a result?

When I resize the browser, the place that invisiblity's border starts is changing

[image: OpenLayers vector map]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason [Map.autoUpdateSize](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.autoUpdateSize) (which is `true` by default) doesn't seem to do its job. I've had the exact same problem and I ended up calling [Map.updateSize()](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.updateSize) explicitly after all actions that affect map container's size, for example from window's `onresize` event.

Comment: Thanks kryger, Map.updateSize() works when client resize the browser, actually I have already tried what you say and, even call Map.updateSize() just after the initializeMap(). But when aplication starts still the browser needs to be resized in order to solve the deffect. Is there any other way to solve that?